# Xamarin Human Verification

Tags: xamarin.forms, verification

I implemented password recovery services with using a sms-service for my app. I can send limited sms. So I need human verification to prevent bots. I tried recaptcha. But I can not find any cross-platform solution to this. I need some suggestion for human verification.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Try below

`var smsMessenger = CrossMessaging.Current.SmsMessenger;
            if (smsMessenger.CanSendSmsInBackground)
                smsMessenger.SendSmsInBackground(Number.Text, Message.Text);`